# Parsing a non-Unicode string with Flask-RESTful

Tags: python-3.x, flask, unicode, flask-restful, cyrillic

I have a webhook developed with Flask-RESTful which gets several parameters with POST.
One of the parameters is a non-Unicode string, encoded in **cp1251**.

Can't find a way to correctly parse this argument using `reqparse`.

Here is the fragment of my code:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('text')
msg = parser.parse_args()
```

Then, I write `msg` to a text file, and it looks like this:

```
{"text": "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd !\n\n\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\n\n-- \n\ufffd \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd."}
```

As you can see, Flask somehow replaces all Cyrillic characters with `\ufffd`. At the same time, non-Cyrillic characters, like `!` or `\n` are processed correctly.

Anything I can do to advise RequestParser with the string encoding?

Here is my code for writing the text to disk:

```
 f = open('log_msg.txt', 'w+')
 f.write(json.dumps(msg))
 f.close()
```

I tried `f = open('log_msg.txt', 'w+', encoding='cp1251')` with the same result.

Then, I tried

```
 f = open('log_msg_ascii.txt', 'w+')
 f.write(ascii(json.dumps(msg)))
```

Also, no difference.

So, I'm pretty sure it's `RequestParser()` tries to be too smart and can't understand the non-Unicode input.

Thanks!

Comment: U+FFFD is the replacement character. Can you show the code for writing the text to disk? Also, please show the output of `ascii(msg)`, to see if the problem happens at parsing or during writing.

Comment: I just updated the question. with additional info.

Comment: Have you seen that the `reqparse` module is deprecated? If this is a bug in `reqparse`, it might not get fixed. But I suspect that the cyrillic characters get replaced with U+FFFD at an earlier stage. You should inspect (and maybe add here) how the value looks directly on the `flask.request` object and how the payload is sent by the client.

Comment: @lenz I saved the raw request using `request.get_data()`, there is correct data. So I assume it's a `reqparse` bug... Yes, now I see that it's nearly deprecated. Will try to parse raw data or find another way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lenz I just made it work, posted the solution as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally found a workaround. Thanks to @lenz for helping me with this issue. It seems that `reqparse` wrongly assumes that every string parameter comes as UTF-8. So when it sees a non-Unicode input field (among other Unicode fields!), it tries to load it as Unicode and fails. As a result, all characters are `U+FFFD` (replacement character).

So, to access that non-Unicode field, I did the following trick.

First, I load raw data using `get_data()`, decode it using cp1251 and parse with a simple regexp.

```
 raw_data = request.get_data()
 contents = raw_data.decode('windows-1251')
 match = re.search(r'(?P<delim>--\w+\r?\n)Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r?\n(.*?)(?P=delim)', contents, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
 text = match.group(2)
```

Not the most beautiful solution, but it works.

Comment: Happy to see it works. I still think you should make sure it's not the client that is declaring the wrong encoding, and fix it on that end if you can.